# Application of package noindentafter to equation environment cancels indentation for two paragraphs after equation

Tags: equations, noindentafter

I don't know if this is an inappropriate usage on my part of the facilities provided by the `noindentafter` package or an inappropriate feature of the package out of specifics of the `equation` environment, but I've found that if I set `\NoIndentAfterEnv{equation}`, the indentation is lost for *two* paragraphs immediately after the  `equation`, as per the below MWE, while the expected behavior is no indentation for a single paragraph. Any suggestions on how to properly apply the package to the `equation` environment or what to do about this issue will be welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{noindentafter}

\NoIndentAfterEnv{enumerate}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{equation}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is not indented.

This is indented. Follows an enumeration:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enough.
\end{enumerate}

I am not indented.

\begin{equation}
x = y \,.
\end{equation}

No indentation here, fine.

No indentation here, undesired.

But this is indented, again.

\begin{equation}
u > v \,.
\end{equation}

No indentation here, fine.

No indentation here, undesired.

Indented again.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not leave a blank line before `equation`; after it it can be used when the text begins a new paragraph. So you don't need the `noindentafter` package for this: just use the proper way of typing in the code. Similarly for `enumerate` (that however can be preceded by a blank line if need be). Avoid that package: it does nothing you can't do more easily with proper input.

Comment: @egreg: Although I don't really disagree with your statement, I do this in order to help me locate visually the environments in the source file text. Btw, there's something I've been pondering on to ask your advice about. It's on a TeX-related topic, but I'd rather ask you via an email. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, no, you *can't* use blank lines for that, because they're significant for typesetting decisions. You can find my email address if you navigate in the home page linked in my profile here.

Comment: @egreg: I thought that having blank lines could help TeX in making for a better performance regarding the page composition because they allowed for some glue in the vertical space before and after displayed mathematical contents. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @egreg: Thank you very much about the possibility of directly contacting you. I'll send you an email today.

Comment: You're wrong in your assumption about glue; for instance, a blank line before `equation` will spoil the spacing in most cases.

Comment: @egreg: Alright. I'll proceed as per your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `equation` environment has some peculiar properties that make it incompatible with `\NoIndentAfterEnv{equation}`.

As a general rule, remember that blank lines in TeX carry a meaning, they're not to be used as “delimiters” or for giving emphasis to something. Some remarks:

1. ***never*** have a blank line before `equation` (or other math display environment);
2. leave a blank line after `equation` (or other math display environment) only if the text actually starts a new paragraph;
3. don't use `noindentafter`.

For `enumerate` the situation is much similar, but depending on the text it *can* be preceded by a blank line (the space above and below will be a bit larger if you do).

Thus the problems you see are better solved by using proper input.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is not indented.

This is indented. Follows an enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enough.
\end{enumerate}
I am not indented.

This is indented. We will have then an enumeration. % note the period

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enough.
\end{enumerate}

This will be indented and the spacing will be wider than above.
\begin{equation}
x = y \,.
\end{equation}
No indentation here, fine.

Indentation here, fine.

This is indented, again.
\begin{equation}
u > v \,.
\end{equation}

This is a new paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to isolate something in the typescript for better emphasis, use `%`, for instance as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is not indented.

This is indented. Follows an enumeration:
%%%
\begin{enumerate}
  \ item Enough.
\end{enumerate}
%%%
I am not indented.

This is indented. We will have then an enumeration. % note the period

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enough.
\end{enumerate}

This will be indented and the spacing will be wider than above.
%%%
\begin{equation}
x = y \,.
\end{equation}
%%%
No indentation here, fine.

Indentation here, fine.

This is indented, again.
%%%
\begin{equation}
u > v \,.
\end{equation}
%%%

This is a new paragraph.
\end{document}
```

But a good editor with colored syntax usually is sufficient.